# Minecraft get list of server's players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to get list of currently connected Minecraft players on some server, using some sort of API.

E.g: `myapi.com/playerlist.php?ip=<SERVER_IP>`

Which results something like this:

```
player1
player2
player3
```

Comment: Are you looking for getting the player list on a server you control, or any online multiplayer server?

Comment: If you would just like the total number of players you can easily get that using https://mcapi.us/ which will just poll the server for you.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Ok, Frank, usually that comment fits, but really not in this case. It's not a dumb question.

Comment: @Fabian There is zero effort shown by the asker. Question validity is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

To see the people playing on a server, click and hold "tab" on your keyboard(while playing in that same server). A list should pop up listing all the current players on the server. Release "tab" to close the list.

Comment: The question is asking for using some API, not in-game.

Comment: oh...whoops

i just probably delete this, shouldn't I?

Comment: It is your choice